# counting value frequency in conditional rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe df like:

```
Name   title freq
A       k1  1
A       k1  1
A       k1  2
A       k1  2
A       k1  2
M       k1  1
M       k1  1
M       k1  1
M       k1  2
M       k1  2
M       k1  2
M       k1  2
A       k2  1
A       k2  1
A       k2  1
A       k2  2
A       k2  2
A       k2  2
A       k2  2
M       k2  1
M       k2  1
M       k2  1
M       k2  1
M       k2  1
M       k2  2
M       k2  2
M       k2  2
M       k2  2
M       k2  2
M       k2  2
```

and I would like to create an output like:

```
title name  freq_1  freq_2
k1    A      2         3
k1    M      3         4
k2    A      3         4
k2    M      5         6
```

I tried:
    df.groupby(['title','name', 'freq']).size().reset_index(name='Number')

and the output was a bit different from what I wanted:

```
      title    name            freq   Number
0        k1     A               1       2
1        k1     A               2       3
2        k1     M               1       3
3        k1     M               2       4
4        k2     A               1       3
5        k2     A               2       4
6        k2     M               1       5
7        k2     M               2       6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

quick answer

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'title', 'freq']).size().unstack()

freq        1  2
Name title      
A    k1     2  3
     k2     3  4
M    k1     3  4
     k2     5  6
```

---

With a bit more formatting

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'title', 'freq']).size().unstack() \
  .rename(columns='freq_{}'.format).rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index()

  Name title  freq_1  freq_2
0    A    k1       2       3
1    A    k2       3       4
2    M    k1       3       4
3    M    k2       5       6
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `pd.crosstab`:

```
(pd.crosstab([df.Name, df.title], df.freq, colnames=[''])
   .rename(columns="freq_{}".format).reset_index())
```

[image]